# PIL saving as a PNG loses ICC profile

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, png, color-profile

I have a JPEG image (which unfortunately I cannot share here) which I'm trying to re-save as PNG, while maintaining its color profile:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

pil_img = Image.open(path_to_jpeg)
# Some processing on the image...
np_img = np.array(pil_img)
Image.fromarray(np_img).save('/path/to/img.png', icc_profile=pil_img.info.get("icc_profile"))
```

Unfortunately, the colors change, so I assume the ICC profile is not saved correctly.
When switching to save a 'jpeg' then the colors are maintained correctly. But I do not wish to save as a jpeg.

Comment: Somewhat hard to debug without an image. As a second strategy, how about extracting the ICC profile from your original image and comparing it with the profile extracted from your output image? Or extracting the profile from your input image and forcing it into your output image using a different tool? My suggestion would be `exiftool` and the techniques you would need are given here https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=4081.0

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have a feeling it would happen with every image (i.e. take any jpeg image with icc profile, open with this code and try to resave as a png). I just couldn't find a jpeg image online with icc profile

Comment: @MarkSetchell OK, so I see the icc_profile is the same in the saved image. But when I open it, it looks different. Perhaps because it's extension is different the icc profile isn't read in the same manner?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the saving works OK, and PyCharm image viewer doesn't read the ICC profile correctly from the PNG files.
So just try to open the saved images with a different viewer (i.e. mac's viewer) and it would work just fine.